# Rails 3.1.8 strange timezone behaviour. subtracting dates.to_i gives zero, ruby says dates are different

Tags: datetime, ruby-on-rails-3.1, timezone

I'm upgrading from rails 3 to 3.1.8 (and onwards).  A couple of my tests are failing, one of which seemed at first glance to be because of the change from mysql2 gem (0.2.x to 0.3.x).  However, it gets a little stranger.  Here's what's happening.

In my test I am updating attributes on a model, and checking that they've saved:

...
    post :create, :advertisement => @advertisement_attributes
    assert_equal assigns(:blah).start_date, @blah_attributes[:start_date]

It is failing saying that they are different times.
If I put a binding.pry and jump in just before the assert_equal this is what I get:

```
a =  assigns(:blah).start_date
b =  @blah_attributes[:start_date]
a == b #false
a.to_s #"2012-10-17 20:46:12 UTC"
b.to_s #"2012-10-17 20:46:12 UTC"
a.to_i #1350506772
b.to_i #1350506772
a.to_i - b.to_i #0
```

So far.. I'm still confused as to why the == is returning false.  But what is *really odd* is if I subtract the dates -

```
a - b #-0.989403009414673
```

If anyone can explain what's going on here I'd love to know!

Also, this same test was passing fine in rails 3 (no timezone was set for the application), any pointers to what has changed would also be handy!

Comment: ahh... still looking into it.. but .. on a subsequent test

    a.to_f = 1350601531.0
    b.to_f = 1350601531.04343

So.. looks like my factory girl is passing more accuracy (perhaps?) than the database (mysql) can handle.

Comment: According to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7385 looks like it was a rounding issue.